# Liquibase doesn't work when the master changelog path is changed

Tags: liquibase

I run my Liquibase using .sh-script where the following is placed:

```
java -jar ./lib/liquibase.jar --driver=${DB_DRIVER} --classpath=${DB_CLASSPATH} --changeLogFile=${DB_CHANGELOG_PATH} --url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVER}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_INSTANCE} --username=${DB_USER} --password=${DB_USER_PW} --logLevel=info --contexts=test update
```

When I pass a new changelog path as a parameter to the script, then Liquibase seems to ignore data inside this changelog.xml file.

Assume, my folder structure is the following:

```
 folder1 +
         |--- lib
         |--- script.sh 
         |--- changelog +
                        |-- VERSION-1.0
                        |-- changelog.xml
 folder2 +
         |--- changelog.xml
```

And current dir is folder1.

I will pass a new changelog let's say like this:

```
./script.sh ./../folder2/changelog.xml
```

And Liquibase executes this new changelog, it is ok, it sees the changes and everything, but when the Liquibase update or Liquibase rollback is executed, it does nothing. I just get "Liquibase Update Successful" or "Liquibase Rollback Successful", but no changesets applied.

Comment: do you use `logicalFilePath` in your changelogs?

Comment: No, why? For what?